# Find the minimum positive period of $35\left[1+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi(t-250)}{365}\right)\right]$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> A producer of plants asked an expert to make a study regarding the
>   profit of his sales.
>
> According with the statistics of previous years, the expert made a
>   model:
>
> $$V(t) = 35\left[1+\sin\left(\frac{4\pi(t-250)}{365}\right)\right]$$
>
> In this model, $V$ represents the daily profit in hundreds of euros
>   and $t$ represents the time in days, starting from the beginning of the
>   year.
>
> Find the minimum positive period of this model.

I tried:

period = $\frac{2\pi}{|b|}$, $b = -\frac{200\pi}{73}$

This is how I got b:
$$\frac{4\pi}{365}\cdot(t-250) = -\frac{1000\pi}{365}t = -\frac{200\pi}{73}t$$

Then, to calculate the period:

$$\frac{2\pi}{\frac{200\pi}{73}} = \frac{2\cdot \pi \cdot 73}{2\cdot 100 \cdot \pi}=\frac{73}{100}$$

But my book says the solution is $182.5$ days. What did I do wrong?

And what is the difference between a normal period and a minimum positive one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally multiplied the $250$ with $\frac{4\pi}{365} t$, that is your mistake.

$$b=\frac{4\pi}{365} \Rightarrow \frac{2\pi}{b} = \frac{365}{2} = 182.5$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, one period of the function:

$$\text{V}\left(t\right)=35\cdot\left\{1+\sin\left(\frac{4\cdot\pi\cdot\left(t-250\right)}{365}\right)\right\}\tag1$$

Is given by:

$$\frac{365}{2}=182.5\tag2$$

---

In general, one period of:

$$\text{a}\cdot\left\{\text{b}+\sin\left(\frac{\text{c}\cdot\text{d}\cdot\left(t-\text{f}\right)}{\text{g}}\right)\right\}\tag3$$

Is given by:

$$-\frac{2\cdot\pi\cdot\text{g}}{\text{c}\cdot\text{d}}\tag4$$